# How to inject CRUDRepository interface to my util class

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, autowired, interceptor

I really dont know why my CRUDRepository interface can't be injected.

I have a small app on Spring Boot and use CrudRepository:

```
public interface ActionLogRepository extends CrudRepository<ActionLog, Integer> {
}
```

In my service class I have a method:

```
@Service
public class ActionRecordServiceImpl implements ActionRecordService {

 @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteActionRecord(Date date, String domain) {

        Set<Action> actions= myActions...(the code delibrately shortened)

        for (Action a : actions) {
                actionRepository.delete(a);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Next I have my Interceptor - I want to catch all delete operations and save these logs in database:

```
public class ActionTrackerInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    // called when record is deleted.
    public void onDelete(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state,
            String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
        Action act = (Action) entity;
        String action = "DELETED";
        ActionLog actionLog = new ActionLog(...some data inserted...);

        MyActionLogUtil util = new MyActionLogUtil();
        util.logIt("DELETED", actionLog);
        actionLogRepository.save(actionLog);
        System.out.println("Record " + entity + " is deleted.");
    }
```

And my method util.LogIt looks like:

```
@Component
public class MyActionLogUtilImpl implements ActionyLogUtil {

    private ActionLogRepository actionLogRepository;

    @Autowired
    public void setActionLogRepository(ActionLogRepository actionLogRepository) {
        this.actionLogRepository = actionLogRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void logIt(String action, ActionLog entity) {

        try {
            ActionLog actionLog = null; // = new ActionLog(...some data inserted...)
            actionLogRepository.save(actionLog);

        } finally {

        }
    }
}
```

When my app is starting, the method setActionLogRepository in MyActionLogUtilImpl is set and ActionLogRepository is correctly injected (not null value). But when debugging, in the method MyActionLogUtilImpl.LogIt **IS MY actionLogRepository NULL!**

My main class with @SpringBootApplication is at the top of the packages so the ComponentScan issue is not the point here.

The question is WHY? Another transaction? I really don't know what's the problem. I've read all similar topics in INternet... Please help me.  Thank you.

Regards
Matley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ActionTrackerInterceptor`:

```
MyActionLogUtil util = new MyActionLogUtil();
```

You are creating a new instance of your "Util" class manually rather than using the one Spring created at application startup (which actually have a correct reference to your repository).

It's not about transaction management, it's about core DI functionality. Make sure you read the [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#spring-core) for further info how DI works in general.

Comment: Ahh, very stupid mistake. OK. Solved. And I have changed INterceptor to Hibernate Listener. In this case, to be able to autowire beans, I had to apply the solution based on https://guylabs.ch/2014/02/22/autowiring-pring-beans-in-hibernate-jpa-entity-listeners/ because Listeners aren't handled by Spring container - we have to manually autowire our beans later.